# Powertop shows 100% GPU usage with Nvidia card on Optimus laptop

Tags: nvidia, 19.10, nvidia-optimus

I freshly installed Ubuntu 19.10 on a Dell XPS 15 9560 with an Nvidia GTX 1050 graphics card. In the "Software & Updates" app, I chose the `nvidia-driver-435` driver. I ran

```
sudo prime-select on-demand
```

and rebooted.

When the laptop is logged-in and idle, the Nvidia settings app shows 0% GPU utilization, but **powertop shows 100% use** for the Nvidia card. This goes down to 0% if I boot with the `nouveau.modeset=0` kernel option, which also seems to greatly improve battery life.

Is Powertop right in showing the GPU used at 100%? What can I do to keep using it on-demand while not eating my battery constantly?

Comment: Why are you using the on-demand setting? It has a very narrow use case..

Comment: @doug I understood it to be something close to Windows's behavior (use Intel by default, and only run programs that need the GPU on the GPU), which I like (I need the GPU for deep learning).

Comment: Not sure what the powertop should be on this, maybe it's not  correct?? With on-demand nvidia.ko will be loaded so battery use will be more than with Intel but should be less than using nvidia full time. That seems to be born out by the  0% GPU utilization. As far a close to Windows behavior, not really, that's done automatically, this has to be done specifically. (most apps won't use nvidia in this mode..